# Slide long image horizontally (full screen)

Tags: html, css, animation

Could do with some help.

I need to slide a long image horizontally once and then back... I've followed a tutorial here https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-css-sliding-background-effect/ and its all working. My problem is I want the sliding image to be fullscreen (the image height needs to fit the browser viewpoint). Current image is 7676 x 3939. background-size: cover was an option but image is too large so it doesn't fit height-wise. So I'd like half the image (3838px - fullscreen) to show initially then slide to the other half and then back.

Would appreciate some assistance. Below is my code. Thanks.

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sliding-background {
    background: url("long-image.jpg") center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 7676px;
    animation: slide 3s linear 1;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0%{
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translate3d(-3838px, 0, 0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add position relative or absolute to .sliding-background

Answer (score 0):

You could also try animating the background position instead of the element itself. Then you should make your container full screen, like this:

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sliding-background {
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Denali_National_Park_Polychrome_Mountains_Wide_17350px.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  animation: slide 45s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/9mLhdy4c/

Comment: Thanks. That's more or less it. Except the image repeats itself. I just have one long image and I want to show say half the image then scroll to the other half and then back. Sorry if I haven't explained it well. So like in the example, it'll show half image till the sun (full screen) then slide to the other half and then back.

Comment: Okay, i've updated the Fiddle, I've change the image for a wider one, and is still full-screen, doesn't show half of the image at the beginning, because that's not the right image aspect radio. You can of course play with the background-position and background-size the get what you have in mind. :)